# Can you use a test for clinical purposes if it is available in a public thesis?

Tags: cognitive-psychology, measurement, clinical-psychology, neuropsychology

The situation is as follows: say you find a Phd/ MSc thesis on a university's online library. In the Appendix part of the thesis, there is a copy of the psychometric tools used, for e.g the digit span test from the WAIS scale.
Would it be okay to take it from there and use it for clinical purposes? Or is it still protected from copyrights? Who could prosecute you?
Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Welcome. Ask the author for legal stuff. Perhaps more important than that -implementing stuff from a thesis in the clinic sounds dodgy.

Comment: I believe default copyright would apply if no specific legal requirements are listed. I.e., include attribution where the survey is used. To be safe, contact the author.